# How can I optimize this function? I need to loop though users, and then loop through user submitted data, and update values, it's taking > 1 minute

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I optimize this function? I need to loop though users, and then loop through user submitted data, and update values, it's taking > 1 minute for 264 users with around 80 records per user.

```
public function calculateUserPoints(){
    set_time_limit(0);
    /* Select users */
    $sql = "SELECT user_id FROM users";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $users = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    /* User guesses Query */

    $ug_sql = "SELECT 
                guesses.guess_id AS r_guess_id, guesses.user_id, guesses.game_id, guesses.team_1_score AS guess_team_1, guesses.team_2_score AS guess_team_2, guesses.joker,
                games.game_id, games.game_team_1, games.game_team_2, games.real_score_team_1, games.real_score_team_2,
                users.user_id AS usr_id
                FROM games
                JOIN users 
                    ON users.user_id = :user_id AND games.real_score_team_1 IS NOT NULL AND games.real_score_team_2 IS NOT NULL
                LEFT JOIN guesses 
                    ON guesses.user_id = users.user_id
                    AND guesses.game_id = games.game_id 
                    ";
    $ug_query = $this->db->prepare($ug_sql);
    foreach($users as $u){ /* Loop users */
        /* Get guesses per user basis */
        /*echo 'User '.$u['user_id'].'<br/>';*/
        $ug_query->bindParam(':user_id', $u['user_id']);
        $ug_query->execute();
        $usr_guesses = $ug_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $u_points = 0;
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET points = :u_points WHERE user_id = :usr_id";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $sql2 = "UPDATE guesses SET guess_points = :guess_points WHERE guesses.guess_id = :guess_id";
        $query2 = $this->db->prepare($sql2);
        foreach($usr_guesses AS $ug){
            $err = false;
            $g_points = 0;
            if(isset($ug['guess_team_1']) && isset($ug['guess_team_1'])){
                $g_points = $this->calcPoints($ug['guess_team_1'], $ug['guess_team_2'], $ug['real_score_team_1'], $ug['real_score_team_2'], $ug['joker']);
            } else {
                $u_points -= 1;
            }
            $u_points += $g_points;
            /*  echo $ug['guess_team_1'].' - '.$ug['guess_team_2'].'  :: '.' '.$ug['real_score_team_1'].' - '.$ug['real_score_team_2'].' jk: '.$ug['joker'].' / pt: '.$g_points.':: T: '.$u_points.'<br/>';*/   

            $query->bindParam(':u_points', $u_points);
            $query->bindParam(':usr_id', $u['user_id']);    
            $query2->bindParam(':guess_points', $g_points);
            $query2->bindParam(':guess_id', $ug['r_guess_id']);             
            if($query->execute() && $query2->execute()){
                $err = false;
            } else {
                $err = true;
            }       
        }   
    }
    if($err == true){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }   

}
```

guess_id and user_id are indexes on all columns.

I'm not looking for a code answer, I'd prefer merely a push in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: #1 - prepared statements are prepared **once**, executed **multiple** times. What you do in your code is prepare the same statement, supply different data. You don't have to do that. Second part is that you're performing an UPDATE query, but there's no transaction present - that makes InnoDB work in autocommit mode - each query is its own transaction. In our regular human language, that means each of your updates is going to spend 1 HDD I/O - and you don't have many of them. That probably kills your performance. Databases like lots of data in 1 I/O.

Comment: How would I implement a transaction in this? I had never heard of it.
I am indeed using innoDB

Comment: Actually, it's solved, it now takes 5 seconds on localhost, the server is actually faster than that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM users";` can be joined with `$ug_sql` query into one query.

If you use InnoDB tables, you can do the updates in transaction, it will speed it up.

And think about removing some indexes, they slow down inserts, updates, and deletes.

Comment: I'd upovote you had you not said "remove some indexes". You can't say that without explaining *which* indexes should be removed (ones with really low cardinality). Otherwise, your answer can be interpreted as if one should avoid indexes completely.